# javascript jump to timestamp video button

Tags: javascript, video, timestamp

I'd like to create either a button or a link that would jump to specific timestamp. So far I succeded with button I got:

```
   <video id="video" src="./movie.m4v" controls></video>    
   <div><button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button" >Go to 5 Sec</button></div>

</p>

<script>

var vid = document.getElementById("video");


function setCurTime() { 
    vid.currentTime=5;
} 
</script>
```

The problem is that if I'd like to create lets say 5 timestamps I'd have to create 5 buttons (and that's ok) plus 5 functions, each jumping to given timestamp (which is bad).
Is there a way to put a variable value after vid.currentTime= that would read a value set in button? So it would be something like

```
    <video id="video" src="./movie.m4v" controls></video>    
   <div><button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button" value="5">Go to 5 Sec</button></div>
   <div><button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button" value="10">Go to 10 Sec</button></div>
   <div><button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button" value="20">Go to 20 Sec</button></div>

</p>

<script>

var vid = document.getElementById("video");


function setCurTime() { 
    vid.currentTime= *valuesetinbutton*;
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to take a variable into `setCurTime()`

Like

```
function SetCurTime(timeValue)
{
  vid.currentTime = timeValue;
}
```

and then use

```
<div><button onclick="setCurTime(5)" type="button" value="5">Go to 5 Sec</button></div>
   <div><button onclick="setCurTime(10)" type="button" value="10">Go to 10 Sec</button></div>
   <div><button onclick="setCurTime(20)" type="button" value="20">Go to 20 Sec</button></div>
```

or you can use it like this

```
function SetCurTime()
{
  vid.currentTime = this.value;
}
```

Comment: No problem! Glad to help out. As a note you could drop off the value attributes if you are doing it the first way...you only need to pass the value into the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `this` that's passed in with the click event.

```
function setCurTime() { 
    vid.currentTime = this.value;
}
```

`this` refers to the element that triggered the event in this case